# How to create an analogue of ThemeProvider from styled-components?

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

What I want: create a Provider, pass in my own props and get it immediately in props in all components (without using useContext).

Comment: Adding additional information including some code will be helpful in getting help.

Comment: I doubt if there is a way to do 'immediately in all components without using useContext'. Context API was designed for that specific purpose. Components which want to receive such props have to explicitly declare it that way.